# Testing inline callback functions in React using Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a component with the following code

```
<Resizable
  ...
  onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, d) => {
    someFunc(d.width)
  }}
  ...
>
```

I want to test the `onResizeStop` prop. I could make a new named function and assign it to the prop but I am not very willing to change the original code for testing purposes.

What should be the ideal way to test this prop. Do I need to make a mock function? How do I compare the real prop value and the expected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mock functions usually **capture all the calls** performed to the function and provide a way to inspect **how many time the mock was called** and the **arguments** it was called with.

Jest's mock functions [make no exception](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html).

```
// Initialize your mock function
const onResizeStopMock = jest.fn();

// Setup your component with React test renderer or Enzyme or any other React renderer tool
<Resizable
  onResizeStop={onResizeStopMock}
>

// Interact with your component and inspect the mock function, eg:

// Mock function was called only once
expect(onResizeStopMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);

// Test the fourth argument of the first call ("d")
expect(onResizeStopMock.mock.calls[0][3]).toEqual({width: 99, height: 99});
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for the help. I was wondering what should be the approach if the Resizable component is part of a big component being tested. How would we set that particular prop to a mock function? Ideally, I would be doing `<MyComponent props={...props}/>` for my setup. This approach doesn't cover the setup for `Resizable`

Comment: When something is hard to unit test, 95% of the times it means there is an underlying architectural decision waiting to be improved. A big component wrapping other components as a black box smells like a not optimal solution.

I see at least 2 solutions in your case: make the big component composable or at least let the big component accept the callback functions of its children via props.